# Passar resultados de um array para variáveis

Tags: php, mysql

A consulta abaixo retorna o número total de registros por modalidade:

```
 $sql = "SELECT modalidade, COUNT(*) as total FROM a_finan GROUP BY modalidade";
 $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error()); 
 while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 

 echo   $linha["total"] . '<br>';
```

Ela me retorna assim:

> 15 
>   10 
>   20

Como passar cada linha de resultado  para uma variável?

Comment: Vale lembrar queas funções mysql_* estão obsoletas. Utilize mysqli_* ou PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para armazenar cada linha de resultado em uma variável, basta criar um `array` e adicionar as linhas nele:

```
$variavel = array();
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))
    $variavel[] = $linha;
```

Deste modo, todos os valores retornados pela query ficarão armazenados em `$variavel`, que poderá ser utilizada da maneira que achar melhor.

**Colocando os Valores em Variáveis Completamente Diferentes**

Com exceção de alguns casos muito específicos, sendo que só me vem a mente o desenvolvimento de Frameworks com carregamento dinâmico de módulos ou classes, ou algo do tipo, não vejo vantagem alguma em se fazer isso, se tratando de uma gambiarra nos demais usos.

Mas, aí vai.

Você pode construir o nome de uma variável em uma string, e então referenciar a variável com este nome duplicando o operador `$`. Por debaixo do pano, o que o PHP faz é simplesmente substituir a variável do tipo string, pelo seu conteúdo, e então referenciar o novo nome de variável. Este procedimento pode ser realizado várias vezes, inclusive.

Implementação:

```
$contador = 0;
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $nome = "variavel" . $contador++; // criamos o nome da variável.
    $$nome = $linha; // criamos a variável propriamente dita.
}

// deste momento em diante, podemos referenciar diretamente as variáveis. Mas devemos tomar cuidado para saber QUAIS variáveis estão definidas e não.

// assumindo que pelo menos 3 linhas foram buscadas no banco de dados, o seguinte código é válido:
echo $variavel0 . "<br>";
echo $variavel1 . "<br>";
echo $variavel2 . "<br>";
```

Considerando o exemplo anterior, e a implementação com `array`, veja como a implementação com `array` é mais simples e da o mesmo resultado no caso da impressão dos valores retornados ao banco:

*Array*

```
foreach ( $variavel as $v )
    echo $v . "<br>";
```

*Variáveis Independentes*

```
$contador = 0;
while ( true ) {
    $nome = "variavel" . $contador++;
    if ( !isset($$nome) ) {
        break;
    }
    echo $$nome . "<br>";
}
```

**Observação**

Para a resposta, executei o seguinte código utilizando `php -f`:

```
<?php

    $linha = array("bla", "blabla", "blablabla");
    $contador = 0;
    foreach ( $linha as $v ) {
            $nome = "variavel" . $contador++;
            $$nome = $v;
    }

    echo $variavel0 . "\n";
    echo $variavel1 . "\n";
    echo $variavel2 . "\n";
```

A saída foi:

```
bla
blabla
blablabla
```

A saída na execução bate com a esperada.

Comment: Eu preciso que cada linha em uma variavel diferente tipo $variavel1[] = $linha;  $variavel2[] = $linha;

Comment: É possível fazer isso? Sim. Mas você precisa ter um excelente motivo pra fazer isso ao invés de usar um `array`, pois o que você faz om isso nada mais do que gambiarrar um `array`. Vou atualizar minha resposta.